# does mysql have wait or timeout function?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I want to get all the recodes from database which is past 3 hours( TIMESTAMPS ) .Is there any MYSQL native function for timeout or wait ?

```
id    recode    timestamps
25  some data    2015-02-16 03:20
```

I want to delete above recode if the timestamps exceed 3 hours. That means

when `2015-02-16 06:20`

Comment: Yes, mysql.connect_timeout refers the time within that it will automatically timeout until and unless your query executing from background.

Comment: I want MYSQL native function.I want if one of my recode is exceed the time limit of 3 hours i want to delete it

Comment: Can you please explain this in detail "I want if one of my recode is exceed the time limit of 3 hours " ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native support to expire rows but you can use the [`event scheduler`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events.html) to do it.

```
CREATE EVENT some_table_purger
ON SCHEDULE EVERY MINUTE
DO
  DELETE FROM some_table WHERE log_date < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 HOUR;
```

Comment: Does it overloading the table ?

Comment: It wouldn't add much load to the database or table if you put an index on log_date.